# Sum of two subsets as close as possible

Tags: algorithm, math

> Mike found a long tape in his home. He proceeded to write some
>   sequence of integers. Now he'd like to cut the tape in such a place
>   that the difference between the sum of the integers on one part and on
>   the other is as close to zero as possible (on one part there has to be
>   at least one number). You're to print the absolute value of this
>   difference.
>
> Input: `n` (2 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>) meaning the amount of numbers
>   written on the tape and then n integers `a`<sub>i</sub> (-10<sup>3</sup>
>   ≤ a<sub>1</sub> ≤ 10<sup>3</sup>) as the numbers written on the
>   tape.
>
> Output: One integer being a minimal absolute value of difference
>   between the two parts.
>
> Example:
>  6 
>  1 2 3 4 5 6
>  Should output:
>  1

I have a feeling I've read a problem like this somewhere before.. I don't know how to solve it, though. I mean, I have a clue but I don't know if it's right. Should I compute the sum of the whole tape first and then compute from left to right till I'm as close to the part being a half of the whole tape as possible? I mean: I sum the numbers from left to right constantly checking if I've exceeded the half of the whole set. If a sum of the subset is equal to the half - we print zero. If the exact half is not possible, we check the closest below and above and output the closest one. Is that OK?

Comment: I don't think that's 100% OK. You don't check the sum from right to left. IMO you have to check on both ways at the same time (from left to right and from right to left).

Comment: But isn't the sum closest to the half always the answer? I believe it is.

Comment: You really need to make an effort when you post your homework assignment. That is how you learn, by trying, by writing code, even if you don't succeed, YOU gain.

Comment: Isn't the algorithm I described above an effort..? I know checking all the possibilites is pointless so I didn't mention "I know that brute force here is pointless" assuming it's obvious. I posted the algorithm I think should be the fastest and asked if there are any better. What's bad in it?

Comment: Have you checked that it works for the example data set??

Comment: Yes it does. We sum the whole set which is 21 so the half is 10.5. Then we sum the following numbers therefore getting sums: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15. As 15 is more than 10.5, we go back to 10 (which has to be the lowest below) and check what's nearer: 15-10.5 or 10-10.5. As it's the latter, we get the subsest: {1,2,3,4} and {5,6} the difference of which is one which is the answer.

Comment: if that's what "output the closest one" means, then yes... how did you calculate the difference? be more precise and less sloppy, algorithms need more formal handling.

Comment: We know the sum of the first subset (which is 10) from the comparisons we have to perform to determine which one is nearer to the half - we just store it in a variable. We also know the sum of the whole set as we have to compute it in the very beggining to calculate the half of the whole sum. Then, the sum of the second subset is sum_of_the_tape-sum_of_the_closest_subset and only a simple substraction of this two subsets remains.

Comment: This is exactly how you would go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at one end of the tape and calculate the sum. Write down the sub-sum (sum up to that number) as you are going along. Now the problem is a simple search problem where we can search the sub-sums for the one closest to the total sum divided by two using for instance [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you. That's the same I wrote above - maybe it wasn't clear enough, as yi_H mentioned, sorry for my sloppy description.

Comment: However, one thing I don't get - how should I divide the total sum by two - working on doubles/floats compromises me on number instability and working on integers makes is not-always-correct for odd sums.

Comment: This turns the `O(n)` algorithm of OP int o an `O(n log(n))` algorithm, but both will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is exactly how you would go about it. You can keep track of the sum of the left partition and the right partition by first summing the array and then subtracting each element from the right sum and adding it to the left sum.

```
auto right_sum = accumulate(tape.begin(),tape.end(),0); // sum all the elements
decltype(right_sum) left_sum = 0;
decltype(right_sum) smallest_difference = abs(right_sum-left_sum);
auto best_partition = tape.begin();
for (auto it=tape.begin();it!=tape.end();++it) {
  left_sum += *it;
  right_sum -= *it;
  if (abs(right_sum-left_sum)<smallest_difference) {
    smallest_difference = abs(right_sum-left_sum);
    best_partition = it;
  } 
}
```